# Rails 6.0.2.1 - “sameSite” attribute set to “none” “secure” attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Firefox error:

> Cookie “_myapp_session” will be soon rejected because it has the
> “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the
> “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read
> https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

"To fix this, you will have to add the Secure attribute to your SameSite=None cookies."

How do I add the secure attribute into my SameSite=None cookie, when using Rails 6?

I do not want to add a separate gem to accomplish this.This error randomly appeared, I assume there was a browser change. Does rails 6 have a native way to fix this? I read this post,

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can configure your session store to use secure cookies in production, just add this to an initializer:

```rb
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_my_app_session', secure: Rails.env.production?
```

You may already have it on `config/initializers/session_store.rb`.

[Documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html) and [pertinent issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39190). This will be fixed in Rails 6.1.

Comment: This gets rid of the error in the web browser console, but breaks the login cookies at least for me in my two rails 6.0 projects.

Comment: @SWoo This is my experience too; I'm in a development environment and attempting to persist an object to my db, and I have to refresh the browser before being able to do so. All these fixes here are hacky, in a bad way.

Comment: I gave up and used the secure_headers gem. I looked at the source a bit and the work to replicate it to just avoid using another gem felt like too much for the effort required.

Answer (score 4):

You need this line in your Rails config file:

```
 # Specify cookies SameSite protection level: either :none, :lax, or :strict. 
 # 
 # This change is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions. 
 # It's best enabled when your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.1. 
 Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :lax
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Update to rails 6.1 (see [documentation here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-6-0-to-rails-6-1) on how to do that)
2. Add the following line to `config/application.rb` (see [the doc here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-dispatch) for details on the `cookies_same_site_protection` option):

```rb
# config/application.rb

...

module YouAppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...

    # Specify cookies SameSite protection level: either :none, :lax, or :strict.
    # This change is not backwards compatible with earlier Rails versions. 
    # It's best enabled when your entire app is migrated and stable on 6.1.
    # Was not in Rails 6.0. Default in rails 6.1 is :lax, not :strict
    config.action_dispatch.cookies_same_site_protection = :strict

    ...
  end
end
```

This line could also be added to `config/environments/development.rb`, `config/environments/production.rb` or to an initializer depending on your needs.

Comment: This worked when updating initializers did not. Thank you